# How to use 'debugger' and 'pry' when developing a gem? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, testing, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

I'm developing a gem, and my Gemfile looks like this:

```
source :rubygems

gemspec

group :development, :test do
  gem "pry"
  gem "debugger"
  gem "rake"
end
```

However, I don't want people to have to install `pry` and `debugger` when running tests, but I also want to be able to require them in my tests (because I'm running tests prefixed with `bundle exec`, and I cannot get it them in my load path if they're not in the Gemfile). How do I achieve this?

Also, when to put gems that I use for development in the gemspec, and when to put them in the Gemfile? I really don't know the difference.

Comment: Do you autogenerate your gemspec?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add gems to your gemspec as a development dependency, like this:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # ...
  s.add_development_dependency 'pry'
  s.add_development_dependency 'debugger'
  s.add_development_dependency 'rake'
end
```

These will only be installed when working on the gem and not when installing the gem itself.

Comment: hmm, this doesn't work for me, do we need to add an explicit require as well?

Answer (score 4):

Just as @andrew-vit said, you can add it to your gem specifications as a development dependency

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
   #...
   spec.add_development_dependency "pry"
   spec.add_development_dependency "debugger"
   #...
end
```

Since this will be a development dependency, you don't want to add `require 'pry'` into your main gem app, so just add it into your `spec_helper.rb` or whatever your test setup file is.

```
require 'rspec'
require 'vcr'
require 'pry'
#...
```

Then when you run your specs, you can still add your `binding.pry` into the code for your sandbox. Make sure your specs run before pushing your code. That way if it breaks, you'll see you forgot a breakpoint in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I can just put them in groups.

```
source :rubygems

gemspec

group :development, :test do
  gem "rake"
end

gem "debugger", :group => :debugger
gem "pry",      :group => :pry
```

This way the contributor can choose to not install them:

```
bundle install --without debugger pry
```

Answer (score 1):

For me a mix of the answers above seems to work. I'm currently running with ruby 2.2.4 and with adding this to the .gempsec:

```
s.add_development_dependency 'pry-byebug'
s.add_development_dependency 'rake'
```

and this for my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'pry'
```

Not sure if that helps anyone.