# Unable to require gems loaded as add_development_dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

In my mygem.gemspec I have the following gem that I only want for the purposes of debugging my ruby gem -

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  ...
  s.add_development_dependency "pry"
  ...
end
```

Then in my Rails generator file I have `require "pry"`, however I get the following error -

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- pry (LoadError)
```

If I change `add_development_dependency` to `add_dependency` it works. Am I doing something wrong?

*Edit:*

*lib/generators/mygem/install_generator.rb*

```
require "pry"

module MyGem
  module Generators
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base

      namespace "mygem:install"

      def process
        binding.pry
      end

    end
  end
end
```

*full stack trace*

```
$ rails g mygem:install
Running via Spring preloader in process 99478
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- pry (LoadError)
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
  from Projects/mygem/gem/mygem/lib/generators/cast/install_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:in `each'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:in `block in lookup'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:in `each'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:in `lookup'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/generators.rb:250:in `find_by_namespace'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/generators.rb:267:in `invoke'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:24:in `perform'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
  from Projects/mygem/themes/sample/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
  from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
  from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

*Edit:*

Here's a sample gem with the problem - https://github.com/ryangrush/stackoverflow_ruby_gem

Comment: what command do you run to get this error?

Comment: I got that when I ran `rails g mygem:install` in the Rails app that's using mygem. The `install_generator.rb` file in the gem is the file that has `require "pry"`

Comment: alright I updated my question

Comment: I tried all the solutions you mentioned, nothing seems to work. Can you reproduce it? I even tried stopping Spring like I saw mentioned somewhere else

Comment: it was much simpler, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Gemfile in root of the project:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry'
end
```

And of course run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it from the gem side, instead of the project side. Again replacing replacing `add_development_dependency` with `add_dependency` in the .gemspec file works too. I don't know I'm out of ideas. I'll probably just use your solution or use add_dependency and move on even though its not ideal. Thanks for your help.

Comment: but your running a `rails generate` command and Rails needs to load gems from your project `Gemfile` so there shouldn't be a problem. And I doubt you want to require pry in a production environment.

Comment: you and @engineersmnky both helped clarify this, thanks. I think I use this solution when debugging my generators rather than loading it as a gem dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand what "development_dependency" means: (This has nothing to do with your `rails` environment as most gems are not dependent on `rails` or environmental flags)

[Taken From RubyGems Guide](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/):

> **DECLARING DEPENDENCIES**...
>
> **Runtime vs. development**
>
> RubyGems provides two main “types” of dependencies: runtime and development. Runtime dependencies are what your gem needs to work (such as rails needing activesupport).
>
> Development dependencies are useful for when someone wants to make modifications to your gem. When you specify development dependencies, another developer can run **gem install --dev your_gem** and RubyGems will grab both sets of dependencies (runtime and development). Typical development dependencies include test frameworks and build systems.
>
> Setting dependencies in your gemspec is easy. Just use **add_runtime_dependency** and **add_development_dependency**:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = "hola"
  s.version = "2.0.0"
  s.add_runtime_dependency "daemons", ["= 1.1.0"]
  s.add_development_dependency "bourne", [">= 0"]
```

So since your gem needs `pry` to work, by your design, then `pry` would be a runtime_dependency. Either that or you need to put some trapping around this code to determine

- a) is `Rails` defined? and;
- b) Are we in the `development?` environment? and;
- c) Is `Pry` defined? or;
- d) can we load `pry` (rescue from `LoadError`)

Comment: so even though I only need pry for debugging my gem and not the Rails app using it, I still have to load it as a runtime dependency? I found some SO answers that had it as an `add_development_dependency` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863281/772309) so I thought it was possible.

Comment: @RyanGrush you are requiring it in the generator which will run in the gem so yes. Your debugging should be done before placing the gem into a rails application. Usually this is done by writing tests to ensure the functionality.

Comment: oh I see the difference now. I just tried loading pry with `add_development_dependency` and using it outside of a generator and it worked. Thanks for helping to clear that up.